# android : get all inbox sms and group by it with month

Tags: android, sms

So, I want to read all the inbox messages and group by month.

With the below code I am able to get all the messages. I am remaining with grouping it with month.

Below is the code I used for getting all the sms:

```
public List<Sms> getAllSms() {
    List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
    Sms objSms = new Sms();
    Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);
    int totalSMS = c.getCount();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

            objSms = new Sms();
            objSms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            objSms.setAddress(c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
            objSms.setMsg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
            objSms.setReadState(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")));
            objSms.setTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).contains("1")) {
                objSms.setFolderName("inbox");
            } else {
                objSms.setFolderName("sent");
            }

            lstSms.add(objSms);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    // else {
    // throw new RuntimeException("You have no SMS");
    // }
    c.close();

    return lstSms;
}
```

**Sms class:**

```
public class Sms {
    private String _id;
    private String _address;
    private String _msg;
    private String _readState; //"0" for have not read sms and "1" for have read sms
    private String _time;
    private String _folderName;

    public String getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return _address;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return _msg;
    }

    public String getReadState() {
        return _readState;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return _time;
    }

    public String getFolderName() {
        return _folderName;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        _address = address;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        _msg = msg;
    }

    public void setReadState(String readState) {
        _readState = readState;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        _time = time;
    }

    public void setFolderName(String folderName) {
        _folderName = folderName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sms{" +
                "_id='" + _id + '\'' +
                ", _address='" + _address + '\'' +
                ", _msg='" + _msg + '\'' +
                ", _readState='" + _readState + '\'' +
                ", _time='" + _time + '\'' +
                ", _folderName='" + _folderName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I want like,

January or Month 1 - 15 sms

February or Month 2 - 45 sms
...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the type of `_time` from `String` to `long` in your `Sms` class:

```
public class Sms {
    private String _id;
    private String _address;
    private String _msg;
    private String _readState; //"0" for have not read sms and "1" for have read sms
    private long _time;
    private String _folderName;

    public String getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return _address;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return _msg;
    }

    public String getReadState() {
        return _readState;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return _time;
    }

    public String getFolderName() {
        return _folderName;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        _address = address;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        _msg = msg;
    }

    public void setReadState(String readState) {
        _readState = readState;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        _time = time;
    }

    public void setFolderName(String folderName) {
        _folderName = folderName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sms{" +
                "_id='" + _id + '\'' +
                ", _address='" + _address + '\'' +
                ", _msg='" + _msg + '\'' +
                ", _readState='" + _readState + '\'' +
                ", _time='" + _time + '\'' +
                ", _folderName='" + _folderName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Then change your `getAllSms()` method:

```
public Map<Integer, List<Sms>> getAllSms() {
    Map<Integer, List<Sms>> smsMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Sms>>();
    Sms objSms = null;
    Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);

    Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);
    int totalSMS = c.getCount();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

            objSms = new Sms();
            objSms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            objSms.setAddress(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
            objSms.setMsg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
            objSms.setReadState(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")));
            objSms.setTime(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));

            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).contains("1")) {
                objSms.setFolderName("inbox");
            } else {
                objSms.setFolderName("sent");
            }

            cal.setTimeInMillis(objSms.getTime());
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

            if (!smsMap.containsKey(month))
                smsMap.put(month, new ArrayList<Sms>());

            smsMap.get(month).add(objSms);

            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    // else {
    // throw new RuntimeException("You have no SMS");
    // }
    c.close();

    return smsMap;
}
```

You can print the list of the SMS with this simple for:

```
Map<Integer, List<Sms>> smsMap = getAllSms();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Sms>> entry : smsMap.entrySet()) {
    Log.d("sms_sample", String.format("Month %d: %d sms", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size()));
}
```

Please note that the months start from 0 (January = 0, February = 1...) as explained in the [Calendar documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)